# Email field not getting returned when using react-native-fbsdk-next

Tags: firebase, react-native, facebook, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I'm stuck on this problem for days and can't seem to find a solution!

I'm using Expo managed react native project, trying to use facebook login for authentification with firebase.

Followed this guide on setting it up: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#facebook

Everything works fine, except no email is being returned. Also, email field in firebase auth shows up empty.

[empty email field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHqB4.png)

I'm calling logInWithPermissions like this and requesting two permissions 'public_profile' & 'email'

```
const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
    'public_profile',
    'email',
  ]);
```

Then i noticed that 'email' permission isnt even asked here?
[only asks for name and profile pic permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYRdA.png)

what could be wrong here? im totaly out of ideas :/

Comment: Same problem I'm facing, try this and let me know if it works for you, didn't for me https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/349#issuecomment-1318261490

Comment: @Chrstopher tried this solution already, same problem, no email is returned.

Comment: I found out that email isn't required for Facebook login. I believe it terrible DevOps  experience but Facebook just doesn't return email sometimes. A work around is using the `userID` for validation